# The [0.0.0] version of the [jdbc] client is not compatible with Elasticsearch version [7.10.0];]

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, jdbc

I have a strange problem with the Elasticsearch JDBC driver version after packaging.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>x-pack-sql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run my code in IDEA to access Elasticsearch, it works normally.

Next, I execute `mvn package` to get a **jar with dependencies**.
When I run this jar to access Elasticsearch, the error is as follows:

```sh
java.sql.SQLException: Server sent bad type [action_request_validation_exception]. Original type was [Validation Failed: 1: The [0.0.0] version of the [jdbc] client is not compatible with Elasticsearch version [7.10.0];]. [org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: The [0.0.0] version of the [jdbc] client is not compatible with Elasticsearch version [7.10.0];
        at org.elasticsearch.action.ValidateActions.addValidationError(ValidateActions.java:26)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.sql.action.AbstractSqlQueryRequest.validate(AbstractSqlQueryRequest.java:239)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.sql.action.SqlQueryRequest.validate(SqlQueryRequest.java:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:144)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:412)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.sql.plugin.RestSqlQueryAction.lambda$prepareRequest$0(RestSqlQueryAction.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:115)
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.rest.SecurityRestFilter.handleRequest(SecurityRestFilter.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:258)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.tryAllHandlers(RestController.java:340)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:191)
        at org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:319)
        at org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.handleIncomingRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:384)
......
```

I guess there was a problem with the version metadata when packaging, but I haven't found a solution.

I found some source code of Elasticsearch that may be useful.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/x-pack/plugin/sql/sql-client/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/sql/client/ClientVersion.java#L112

Comment: How are you running the jar? Are your dependencies in your classpath?

Comment: I have package dependencies into the final jar via maven-assembly-plugin, and execute `java -jar xxx-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/x-pack/plugin/sql/sql-client/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/sql/client/ClientVersion.java#L112

I add the following configuration to pom.xml, and the issue is solved.

```xml
<manifestEntries>
    <X-Compile-Elasticsearch-Version>7.10.0</X-Compile-Elasticsearch-Version>
</manifestEntries>
```